# Force Angular 2 view to update from data

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 (beta 0) component whose value changes based on code outside of Angular. I can listen for this and execute code whenever such a change has happened, but I don't know what code to run to force the Angular 2 view to update.

If I grab a reference to the NgZone being run when my component is initialized, I can then call `ngZone.run(function() { /* do nothing */});` and it forces an update. However, I don't know if that's something I should do, and even if it is, I'm not sure what's a legitimate way to get a reference to the ngZone of my app.

How should I do this?

[edit] In Angular 1.x I would do `$scope.$apply()` but that's not in Angular 2. Other people have suggested doing a `setTimeout(function() { /* do stuff */ })` but that doesn't seem to get hooked by the NgZone (it *is* hooked by a normal Zone), and so doesn't trigger a check for changes.

Comment: Use [`ApplicationRef.tick()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.ts#L344)

Comment: Where do I get ApplicationRef?

Comment: applicationRef doesn't appear to work as an injectable thing in a component constructor.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/JuoYfadSRDaI7VKX1Hi8?p=preview).

Comment: Earlier comments removed, I'd misunderstood the example. I'm using ES5, and your example makes it look like I should just be able to add a parameter to my component constructor called `applicationRef`, however that results in an injector error. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't write angular2 using ES5, but this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6HOqj88GQcFOAW6fgPK5?p=preview) worked for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. Unlike in Angular 1, not all injectable dependencies for components can be inferred from the parameter name. In my case, I got access to the NgZone and then bound changes in the zone like this:

```
customSelect = ng.core
    .Component({
        selector: 'custom-select',
        templateUrl: 'select.html',
        properties:[
            'valueProperty:valueProperty',
            'value:value',
            'options:options'
        ]
    })
    .Class({
        constructor:[ng.core.NgZone, function(zone) {
            this.zone = zone;
        }],
        ngOnInit:function() {
            this.unbindChanges = this.valueProperty.bindChanges(function() {
                this.zone.run(function() {
                    this.value = this.valueProperty.currentValue();
                }.bind(this));
            }.bind(this));
        },
        ngOnDestroy:function() {
            this.unbindChanges();
        }
    });
```